# Atualmente é seguro usar font-face em vez de cufon e similares?

Tags: html, css, html5, css-font-face, cufon

Estou trabalhando num site e preciso de utilizar fontes que talvez o usuário não possua na sua máquina. Hoje em dia os navegadores mais utilizados já suportam `@font-face`? A partir de quais versões? Já é possível abrirmos mão de alternativas como o **[cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)**?

Comment: Caso esteja trabalhando com html 5 e css3, acredito que a melhor opção seja a font-face por ser já nativo do CSS3. Caso contrário, e esteja ainda utilizando css2, te aconselho a utilização do Cufon.

Answer (score 4):

Utilize font-face fazendo um *import* da fonte no teu código:

```
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v10/ayfRv9GMahGqd-q6YxHjSg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Lato Regular'), local('Lato-Regular'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v10/1YwB1sO8YE1Lyjf12WNiUA.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}
```

E aplicando a fonte no teu css

```
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
```

Que **qualquer *browser*** rodará sua fonte sem problemas. **Inclusive o IE(ca)**