# O que é cufon e para que serve?

Tags: javascript, html, cufon

Recentemente quando eu estava a ver o código fonte de um tema Wordpress antigo, eu deparei-me com um código javaScript que continha o seguinte:

```
Cufon.replace('#navigation > ul > li > a', {
    textShadow: '1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)',
    hover: {
        color: linksColor
    }
});
```

Isto foi apenas um dos sítios onde encontrei o tal `cufon`, mas encontrei-o também em vários outros lugares ao longo do código javaScript. O que me levou à pergunta - O que é `cufon`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O [Cufon](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) é uma API que tem como função substituir fontes em javascript.

Usando HTML5 e CSS3 é possível utilizar o `font-face` ao invés do Cufon como foi discutido [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/31541/atualmente-%C3%A9-seguro-usar-font-face-em-vez-de-cufon-e-similares).

Answer (score 2):

Cufon é uma maneira antiga de se usar fontes "não seguras" antes de aparecer o `@font-face`.
Ela era uma técnica JavaScript utilizada como alternativa para as WebFonts e [sIFR](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIFR).

O que ele faz é sobrepor o texto real com uma imagem, para que mantenhamos o texto para o SEO, e ao mesmo tempo vermos uma fonte agradável (que é uma imagem). O Cufon sempre foi muito limitado em termos de CSS, que foi uma das suas restrições e que foi bastante inseguro.

#### Como usá-lo e onde posso ver um exemplo?

A primeira coisa que precisamos de fazer é o download do arquivo javaScript responsável pela renderização da sua fonte personalizada do seu HTML. Como o @psNytrancez já mencionou, podemos fazer o download através do link - <kbd>[Cufon Generate](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/)</kbd>

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 2º Passo - Gerar a fonte

Nesta mesma página: http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/ - clique no campo "Regular typeface" - e navegue até ao directório da fonte desejada na sua máquina local.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#### 3º Passo: "Cufonize" a sua página

Tudo o que você precisa de fazer a partir deste ponto é conectar esses arquivos javascript ao seu documento HTML (como normalmente se faz com a biblioteca jQuery por exemplo). Certifique-se também de que o **Cufon-yui.js** é chamado primeiro que o arquivo **font.js**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="Gigi_400.font.js"></script>
```

Para iniciar o processo de substituição - crie um `script` personalizado como no exemplo abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    Cufon.replace('h3, p');
</script>
```

Com a biblioteca jQuery implementada, você pode selecionar elementos mais específicos na sua página como no exemplo de código abaixo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    Cufon.replace('h3#convert-me, p#convert-me-too');
</script>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

fonte das imagens e instruções - [Cufonize Your Pages](http://fearlessflyer.com/cufonize-your-pages-how-to-add-cufon-to-your-web-design/)